# ngxs State not getting initialised on the first load

Tags: angular, ngxs

I am calling the my service method to fetch records and updating the state (ngsx) with boolean value if record exists. If record exists i am setting the agreementExists value in the state to true else setting it to false. I am trying to load the modal dialog in the app component and subscribing to the observable to check if record exists. At the moment the first time when the app component loads the  agreementModalStatus itself is undefined and gets initialised only after refresh. Could somebody tell me what the problem is. How can i tackle this issue

appcomponent

```
public ngOnInit() {
    this.agreementModalState$.pipe(first()).subscribe(agreementModalStatus => {
      console.log('Inside ngOnit- AppComponent');
      console.log(agreementModalStatus.agreementExists);
      console.log(agreementModalStatus.isInteracted);
      if (agreementModalStatus !== undefined && agreementModalStatus.isInteracted === false && agreementModalStatus.agreementExists) {
        this.loadModalDialog();
     }
   });
  }

  public loadModalDialog() {
    this.modal = this.modalService.open(AgreementComponent, { size: 'lg', centered: true , backdrop: 'static'});

  }
```

component

```
public getOutstandingAgreements(Id: number) {
    this.loading = true;
    this.agreementsService
      .getOutstandingAgreements(Id)
      .subscribe((data: AgreementsModel[]) => {
        if (data.length > 0) {
          console.log('IF block');
          this.store.dispatch(new SetAgreementStatus({ isInteracted: false , agreementExists: true}));
          this.myData = data;
          this.agreementData = this.myData[0].data;
          this.agreementLength = this.myData.length;
          this.SetWarningMessage(0);
          this.loading = false;
        } else {
          console.log('Else block');
          this.store.dispatch(new SetAgreementStatus({ isInteracted: false , agreementExists: false}));
        }
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your state class near your decorator.  Did you provide defaults and as such is the default undefined initially?  If so that is why you have one "notification" of undefined. Then you will get the real notification after that one in the stream.